# Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to push my rails app to Heroku, and I keep getting the following error:

```
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!     
!     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
!     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Here is what my gemfile looks like:

```
group :devlopment, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Its highly recommended to do your development w/ the same database as production.  See this article (note at the bottom it also has a note about the sqlite error even if its not in the gemfile): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Try asking your Rails project for a dependency-list for `production` mode. See if there's any other gem you're using that might be using SQLite indirectly.

Comment: Typo, `development`, not `devlopment`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
group :development, :test do # <<<< :development, not devlopment
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

As heroku ignores development specific gems, when running the bundle it includes sqlite3 gem.

Comment: It does answer the question. Heroku bundles `--without development`. It does not bundle without developmnt. Fixing this typo fixes the problem.

Comment: @tyler Indeed this is the answer, because heroku igonres development specific gems. I just updated the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 34):

I have modified the gem file to use sqlite only on development, and test.

But, my mistake was: **I have forgotten to commit the changes on git.**

Comment: also i think after adjusting the Gemfile, you also have to do bundle install or bundle update.. or sometimes,  bundle install --without production

Answer (score -1):

Try using this for production

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Additional information can be found here: [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#getting-a-sqlite-error-even-though-it-is-not-in-the-gemfile)

Answer (score -1):

For me I solve this issue by replacing `gem 'sqlite3'` with `gem "pg"` in the gemfile

and then ofcourse  `heroku restart` and `heroku rake db:migrate`

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
heroku rake db:reset
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Please DO NOT do this