# How to fix "sqlite3.h is missing"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do some project in ruby and make like this

git commit -am "Add hello"
heroku create
git push heroku master

then I got this error

```
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:         --with-opt-dir
remote:         --without-opt-dir
remote:         --with-opt-include
remote:         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:         --with-opt-lib
remote:         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:         --with-make-prog
remote:         --without-make-prog
remote:         --srcdir=.
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:         --with-opt-dir
remote:         --without-opt-dir
remote:         --with-opt-include
remote:         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:         --with-opt-lib
remote:         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:         --with-make-prog
remote:         --without-make-prog
remote:         --srcdir=.
```

I tried to change my gemfile like this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3 and this tutorial [Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297160/detected-sqlite3-gem-which-is-not-supported-on-heroku) but nothing changed.

I tried to install sqlite3 by this

```
gem install sqlite3
```

and success, but nothing changed. It still give me error when I want to push heroku master.

Could you please give me any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you changed your Gemfile like instructed in that tutorial? Did you follow every step including bundle install?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I tried to create a new rails project. I solved it by running this command(based on the instruction from the terminal output error message) on the Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`
Then after the installation, I recreate the project and it works.
I assume that `sqlite3` is installed on your computer. If it is not installed you can run this command `sudo apt install sqlite3` then you can run the above command.

Answer (score 0):

After removing sqlite from gemfile (or making it be only in development/test group) - run `bundle install` and commit changes.

Point is that heroku is container-based, you need to distinguish that from your local machine - local files are only getting there when they are committed and pushed, then heroku builds a readonly (stricly speaking, its "disk" can be written, but all changes can be lost at any time) container that it then runs.

Answer (score 0):

From [a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/b3wzv2/ruby_on_rails_sqlite3h_is_missing/ej2sn3t/) I just read, there was an error with SQLite versioning in RoR lately, and it COULD be related to that. Indicating a **specific version of SQLite** like in the following actually did the trick for me!

So in your Gemfile, replace this:

`gem 'sqlite3'`

with this:

`gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '< 1.4'`